# Query least one item of array Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

Suppose I have documents like this:

```
{
   "name":"Foo",
   "interests":{
      "movies":[
         1,
         2,
         3
      ],
      "music":[
         8,
         9,
         10
      ]
   }
}
```

How do I query for documents that match at least one of array items given an integer number?

Example: How to query all documents that `interests.movie` has `1`?

All query examples I had tried turned into an exclusive match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much how you described:

```
GET movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "interests.movies": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't returning any results. Guess it is considering an exact match, isn't?

Comment: well, it looks for an item 1 in movies. so it might depend on how you created index itself. I created with { "name":"Foo", "interests":{ "movies":[1, 2, 3], "music":[8, 9, 10] }}. And it finds movie.